# cmake cannot find c compiler even though gcc and g++ are installed

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to install `cmake` by executing the command:

```
./bootstrap
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CC.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
```

I have `gcc` and `g++` version 4.8.5 installed. When I run:

```
sudo./bootstrap
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake 3.19.0, Copyright 2000-2020 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc   
C++ compiler on this system is: g++  -std=gnu++1y  
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate Makefile processor on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable MAKE.
```

Please help me resolve this error and install `cmake`.

Comment: Hi! I edited your question and removed your second question about how to make `gcc` available without root user permission, so that this one won't be [closed as needing more focus](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions). You can ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `make` before installing `cmake`:

```
sudo apt install make
```

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Installing cmake with `sudo apt install cmake` also installs make as a recommended package.